# how framesize changes throughput for different size messages

Tags: rabbitmq

While testing the performance of RabbitMQ, I found that after increasing the message size above around 250 KB the throughput was decreasing very quickly. Then I changed the frame_size to 5MB from 256KB and I got, as expected increase in the throughput. This increase was also for the message of smaller size i.e. for message of size 50 KB, throughput increases from 700 to 1100 messages per sec. and that for messages of size 10,000 KB it increases from 2 to 3 messages per sec.

My question is : Can somebody explain me how the messages are passed on wire from client to the broker and vice versa. If the size of message is greater than the size of frame then, I guess multiple frames will be made for that message(that's why, I think, when frame size was 256 KB and message size was increased from 256 KB there was large drop in throughput). But if the size of message is say around 1/10th the size of frame, then is it that each frame will be now holding 10 messages (if 10 messages are ready to be delivered).

If it is so, then say if 10 messages are not ready then for how much time the frame will wait so as to have 10 messages, means there has to be some time out after which the frame will deliver any number of message it is currently holding.

I think I have put all required observations in the question. Any help is warmly welcome.

Comment: Why nobody is replying ? 
Am I unclear at any point or do you need more description... Please reply ASAP.